Characterizing congruences on the algebra of natural numbers
I'm trying to do Exercise 31 in Jan Rutten's book on coalgebras. The goal is to show that, given a characterization of congruences on the initial $N$-algebra $(\mathbb{N},[\text{zero},\text{succ}])$, the induction proof principle for $(\mathbb{N},[\text{zero},\text{succ}])$ is the principle of mathematical induction. First we have to prove the given characterization of congruences on $(\mathbb{N},[\text{zero},\text{succ}])$, which states that:

A relation $R \subseteq \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}$ is an $N$-congruence if and only if $(0,0)\in R$ and for all $(n,m) \in \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}$, $(n,m) \in R \implies (\text{succ}(n),\text{succ}(m)) \in R$.

Here, $N: \text{Set} \to \text{Set}$ maps a set $X$ to $1+X$, its disjoint union with a singleton, and $f:X \to Y$ to $1+f:X \to Y$, which maps the singleton in $1+X$ to the singleton in $1+Y$ and $x\in X$ to $f(x)\in Y$.
I started with the direction I thought might be easier, by assuming $(R,[z,s])$ is a congruence with projections $\pi_1$ and $\pi_2$ to $\mathbb{N}$. So the congruence diagram commutes, and due to initiality of $(\mathbb{N},[\text{zero},\text{succ}])$, we also have a unique morphism $P: (\mathbb{N},[\text{zero},\text{succ}]) \to (R,[z,s])$.

I named the $N$-algebra homomorphism $P$ so that the diagram for that would define the inductive premise, $P(0)=z(*)$ and $P(n+1)=s(P(n))$. I don't know if that was the right move.
But anyway, then I can prove the part first part of the characterization using a special case of what's given in Rutten's proof of the induction proof principle:

$(0,0) \in R$ because initiality implies $\pi_1\circ 
P(0)=1_\mathbb{N}(0)=0$ as well as $\pi_2\circ P(0)=1_\mathbb{N}(0)=0$, so that $P(0)=(0,0)$, meaning that (0,0) must be in the codomain $R$ of $P$.

But I'm struggling to see how I can use the functions in this diagram to show that $(n,m)\in R \implies (n+1,m+1)\in R$. My main roadbloack is that starting with $(n,m)\in R$, I need to chase $(n,m)$ from either $1+R$ or $R$ to $R$, but the only way to end up in $R$ is to go through $P$, which I know maps a natural number $n$ to $(n,n)$ - so I don't see how I could use anything that goes through $P$ to show an element $(n,m)\in R$ for any $m\neq n$.
Here's the closest I got:

Let $(n,m)\in R$. Then,
$$P(\text{succ}(\pi_1(n,m)))=P(\text{succ}(n))=P(n+1)=(n+1,n+1)\in R,$$
$$P(\text{succ}(\pi_2(n,m)))=P(\text{succ}(m))=P(m+1)=(m+1,m+1)\in R,$$

But this is not $(n+1,m+1)\in R$. I'm not sure where I'm going wrong.

I don't know why I didn't realize I could also get to $R$ using $[z,s]$.
Starting at $1+R$ and going both ways around the squares, I get:
$$\text{succ}(\pi_1(n,m))=\text{succ}(n)=n+1=\pi_1([z,s](n,m))$$
$$\text{succ}(\pi_2(n,m))=\text{succ}(m)=m+1=\pi_2([z,s](n,m))$$
So $[z,s](n,m)=(n+1,m+1)\in R$.
Chasing $*\in 1+R$ around the squares similarly yields $[z,s](*)=(0,0)\in R$.
